# Как произвести перебор двух массивов объектов в JS и внести изменение в первый массив совпадающих объектов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите, как при сравнение двух массивов объектов внести изменения в первый массив совпадающих объектов?
Например, в foundMovies изменить status на true у тех, кто находится в массиве объектов nominates

```
const foundMovies = [
  {title: 'IronMan', year: '2010', id: '1234', status: false},
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345', status: false},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456', status: false},
  {title: 'Blizzard', year: '2011', id: '4567', status: false},
];

const nominates = 
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345'},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456'}
;
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно таким образом сделать это. Если требуется изменить именно первый массив, а не создавать новый, то подойдёт метод `forEach`. Проходим весь массив и проверяем есть ли в nominates объект с тем же id.

```
const foundMovies = [
  {title: 'IronMan', year: '2010', id: '1234', status: false},
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345', status: false},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456', status: false},
  {title: 'Blizzard', year: '2011', id: '4567', status: false},
];

const nominates = [
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345'},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456'}
];

foundMovies.forEach((movie) => {
  if (nominates.some(({ id }) => id == movie.id)) {
    movie.status = true;
  }
});

console.log(foundMovies);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно, например, такими двумя способами.

1. Если массивы небольшие, можно обойтись более коротким кодом:

```js
const foundMovies = [
  {title: 'IronMan', year: '2010', id: '1234', status: false},
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345', status: false},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456', status: false},
  {title: 'Blizzard', year: '2011', id: '4567', status: false},
];

const nominees = [
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345'},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456'}
];

for (const movie of foundMovies) {
  if (nominees.find(nominee => nominee.id === movie.id)) movie.status = true;
}
console.log(foundMovies);
```

2. Если массивы большие, первый вариант будет медленным, потому что второй массив для каждого элемента первого будет перебираться заново до первого найденного совпадения. Чтобы повысить эффективность, можно создать промежуточную вспомогательную структуру — объект с ключами из идентификаторов.

```js
const foundMovies = [
  {title: 'IronMan', year: '2010', id: '1234', status: false},
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345', status: false},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456', status: false},
  {title: 'Blizzard', year: '2011', id: '4567', status: false},
];

const nominees = [
  {title: 'Text Me If You Can', year: '2014', id: '2345'},
  {title: 'Wrong Way', year: '2012', id: '3456'}
];

const nomineeIds = Object.fromEntries(
  nominees.map(nominee => [nominee.id, true])
);
for (const movie of foundMovies) {
  if (nomineeIds[movie.id]) movie.status = true;
}
console.log(nomineeIds);
console.log(foundMovies);
```